# How can i create a blue box (w=80px, h=120px) at the center top in mjml?

Tags: email, mjml

I am new to mjml and dont know whwats possible and what not.

I would like to have a blue box at the center top of my mjml but nothing seems to work...
when i acheive the box, i cant seem to change the width or the height, it always takes up the entire width.

I tried adding a new section and also new columns but the width and height for some reason are always ignored

what should i enter after the color or what do I have to add, to have nothing on the sides and a blue 80px wide and 120px high box in the center top of my page?

`<mjml>`
`<mj-body>`
`<mj-section background-color="#009fe3">`
`</mj-section>`
`</mj-body>`
`</mjml>`

Answer (score 0):

you can add height by using mj-text.
check here: https://mjml.io/try-it-live/AZr2yCtkg

CODE:

```
   <mjml>
      <mj-body>

        <mj-section padding="0px">
          <mj-column width="80px" background-color="blue">
            <mj-text height="120px" padding="0px">&nbsp;</mj-text>
          </mj-column>
        </mj-section>

      </mj-body>
    </mjml>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).